# Creating a Primary Key or Unique Index on a URL Column

Tags: sql-server, primary-key, unique-index

Is it possible to create a primary key or unique index on an NVARCHAR(4000) column used to hold URLs? There appears to be a 900 byte limitation on unique indexes in SQL 2008.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is better to create a prefixed index on, say, first `50` characters for fast lookups and a `UNIQUE` index on the `MD5` hash (or another hash which is unique enough).

```
CREATE TABLE urls (url NVARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL, url_prefix AS LEFT(url, 50), url_hash AS HashBytes('MD5', url))

CREATE INDEX ix_urls_prefix ON urls (url_prefix)

CREATE INDEX ix_urls_hash ON urls (url_hash)
```

Comment: Thanks. Does SQL Server have a built-in MD5 function?

Comment: @Mark: yes, it is called `HashBytes`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx